# Seller PayPal account not receiving payment on REST API payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to implement server side paypal rest api in django rest framework,i have to say paypal's documentation is not helping matters at all,but so far i have been able to successfully pay money from a sandbox buyer account by first getting access token:

```
def generate_access_token():
    url="https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"
    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    auth=(settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,settings.PAYPAL_SECRET_KEY)
    data={
        "grant_type":"client_credentials"
        }
    response=requests.post(url,headers=headers,auth=auth,data=data)
    token=response.json()['access_token']
    return token
```

Then i create an order for the buyer to pay:

```
def pay_for_order(token,price,order_id):
    url="https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders"
    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':f'Bearer {token}'
        }
    data={
        'intent':'CAPTURE',
        'application_context':{
            'return_url':f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/confirm-payment/1/{token}/',
            'cancel_url':f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/confirm-payment/2/{token}/'
            },
        'purchase_units':[
            {
               "reference_id":f'{order_id}',
               "amount":{
                   'currency_code':'USD',
                   'value':f'{price}'
                   }
                }
            ]
        }
    response=requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=json.dumps(data))
    print(response.json())
    response_json=response.json()
    return response_json
```

then the order capture is called in the endpoint in the return url when payment is successful like this:

```
def final_payment_verification(token,paypal_token):
    url=f'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/{paypal_token}/capture'
    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':f'Bearer {token}'
        }
    response=requests.post(url,headers=headers)
    print(response.json())
    response_json=response.json()
    return response_json
```

but the major issue now is that the seller doesn't get credited my intuition was that generating access token with seller's client id and secret key already stands as identification for whoever the buyer's payment is going to but unfortunately only the buyer get's debited,i checked the whole order api on paypal docs but couldn't find fields that require buyers or recipient info so paypal can pay to them,all solutions online are for client side checkout and paypal docs are not helping matters at all,there are even some read more pages that lead to totally diffrent unrelated content and every resource online mostly use the v1 version other than the latest v2,I would really like to know what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The code is in sandbox mode, so you must be using a sandbox client ID and secret. Are you looking in the [seller sandbox account](https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdashboard%2Faccounts) (open a separate tab to log in to [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com) with it) that corresponds to the [REST APP client ID and secret](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) you are using?

If you still have issues, log the entire capture API response body and include it in your question.